# I want load minify js file by RequieJs

Tags: requirejs

We want to load module using RequireJs.

By the way, the test server should load 'tab.js',

and the real server should load 'tab.min.js'.

We use RequireJS in the Multiple Page Application.

We are using it like "require('tab', function () { ... });" in html files.

So it is difficult to change the name of the loaded module.

```
// test server
require('tab', function (Tab){ ... } // => load tab.js

// real server
require('tab', function (Tab){ ... } // => load tab.min.js
```

Is there any way to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use two RequireJS configurations:

1. For the test server, set the configuration so that `tab.js` is loaded. How you'd do this depends on specifics you don't provide in your question. A generic way to do it would be to have a `paths` setting like:

   ```
   paths: {
     tab: "path/to/tab",
   }
   ```

   Remember not to put the `.js` extension in the path you provide.
2. For the production server (i.e. the "real" server), set the configuration so that `tab.min.js` is loaded. The example above would be modified to:

   ```
   paths: {
     tab: "path/to/tab.min",
   }
   ```

Comment: however, there are many module. It is impossible to register it all.

Comment: No, it's not impossible.